# toggling stm32 led using structure types

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

hello i am new with the stm32 board i am trying to toggle the user led that is connected to port A pin 5 (nucleo l476rg board) , I wrote this program from scratch using structure types but unfortunately the led is not blinking … I double checked all the addresses because i tried it without the structures and it worked , can any one tell me what’s the problem here ? here's the code:

```
// Port A
// pin  5
#include <stdint.h>
#define periph_base             (0x40000000UL)
#define ahb2_offset         (0x08000000UL)
#define ahb2_base           (periph_base + ahb2_offset)
#define ahb1_offset         (0x20000UL)
#define ahb1_base           (periph_base + ahb1_offset)
#define gpioa_offset                (0x000000UL)
#define gpioa_base          (ahb2_base + gpioa_offset)
#define rcc_offset          (0X1000UL)
#define rcc_base            (ahb1_base + rcc_offset)
#define rcc_ahb2enr_offset              (0x4CUL)
#define rcc_ahb2enr         (*(volatile unsigned int *)(rcc_base +rcc_ahb2enr_offset))
#define gpioa_moder_offset              (0x00UL)
#define gpioa_moder             (*(volatile unsigned int*)(gpioa_base +gpioa_moder_offset))
#define odr_offset          (0X14UL)
#define odr                 (*(volatile unsigned int*)(gpioa_base + odr_offset))
#define gpioa_en            (1U<<0)
#define pin5                (1U<<5)
#define led_pin             pin5
typedef struct
{   
volatile uint32_t MODER;
volatile uint32_t DUMMY[4]; 
volatile uint32_t ODR;
}gpio_Typedef;
typedef struct
{
volatile uint32_t DUMMY[16];
volatile uint32_t AHB2ENR;
}rcc_Typedef;

#define RCC         ((rcc_Typedef*) rcc_base)
#define GPIOA       ((gpio_Typedef*) gpioa_base)

int main(void)
{
RCC->AHB2ENR    |= gpioa_en;
GPIOA->MODER    |= (1U<<10);
GPIOA->MODER    &=~ (1U<<11);
while(1)
{

GPIOA->ODR  ^= led_pin;
for(long int i =0; i<100000;i++){}
}
}
```

Comment: No idea what the definition of `gpioa_base`, but the most likely answer is your alignment is off. The best way to test it would be to write a test without using the struct that toggles a specific bit. Then refactor it to use the struct. If the test still passes, that eliminates that. It it fails, that's your problem.

Comment: Also are you writing this in C or C++? They are two different languages. You should only tag one unless your question is actually about both C and C++.

Comment: The for-loop is probably removed by the compiler. Make i volatile or put a nop inside the loop

Comment: I calculated this last night and I think you need 17 dummy uint32_2 in `rcc_typeDef`. But disassemble your code to be sure, it was very late and I could be wrong.

Comment: "the led is not blinking" Does it seem to be lit up at all times or is it off? Measure the signal with your oscilloscope.

Comment: Why do you spend time writing these struct definitions? They already exist. Use CMSIS. See e.g. `RCC_TypeDef` in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/STMicroelectronics/cmsis_device_l4/master/Include/stm32l476xx.h. It also shows that there are 19 and not 16 elements before `AHB2ENR`.

Comment: @Codo That would be ST-specific libs and not CMSIS, yeah? Still, usually best not to reinvent the wheel when it can be avoided.

Comment: @Codo as i told you i am new with the stm32 this is my first project am following a tutorial , i am trying to understand the structures and how they are built ,

Comment: @codo thanks mate ! the problem was as you said the dummy array has 19 as size not 16

Comment: @Codo but in the reference manual i checked the rcc register map there are only 16 registers  that's kinda weird

Comment: @Lundin It's certainly ST-specific. But STM still calls it CMSIS. I don't know if it has a less confusing name. It consists of a number of header files on top of the MCU-independent CMSIS.

Comment: @RaedBanneni The number of registers is not relevant. The resulting register address must match. The difference is likely because not all addresses in the relevant range are used as registers.

Comment: Use STM provided definitions. To define all registers H7 has you need at least a year

Answer (score 0):

It appears that i had the wrong reference manual , in the rcc_Typedef Structure the dummy array should have 19 as size not 16 , there are 19 registers before the rcc_ahb2enr .